# Why member can't sign in when migrate membership database from ASP.NET MVC3 to MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-membership, asp.net-mvc-4

I manually migrate data from ASP.NET membership database to new membership structure in ASP.NET MVC4. (table name has changed from aspnet_users to Users, aspnet_membership to Memberships, and so forth)

But when try to sign in using ASP.NET MVC4 sign in dialog, it can't signed in.
So I wonder that if default hash algorithm changed in MVC4 or not.

Why member can't sign in?
or How can I set the hash algorithm to Sha1? 
or How to migrate membership database to MVC4 correctly?

Comment: Do you get any exceptions/errors?

Comment: It shows "The user name or password provided is incorrect." in sign in dialog. (no error or exception)

Comment: how did you migrate the data?

Comment: I used the INSERT INTO <new membership table> SELECT * FROM <old membership table>.

Answer (score 0):

Hash algorithm is not related to ASP.NET MVC binaries. It is highly likely that you misconfigured something.

On solution explorer inside VS, click on your project and there should be an icon (with a world and hammer side by side [it is scary I know] I guess) just top of your solution as follows :

[image]

Click on it to fire up the configuration manager. See if you can configure your membership data there. If not, it is sure that you misconfigured something.

**UPDATE :**

Please also be sure that you have configured the `passwordFormat` inside the web.config correctly. It should be same as your old one.

If your `passwordFormat` has been set to `Encrypted` on your old app, then you should use the same machine key which you have used to create passwords before.

Comment: I can open the configuration manager, view, and manage users and roles. if I add new user (sign up or create new user), that user can sign in successfully. but for old users that I migrate (copy) data from old membership tables to new tables (universal provider?) can't sign in to MVC4 app.

Comment: I think default is Sha1, not Encrypted. Am i right?  (PasswordFormat in the table is "1")

Comment: @SuthepSangvirotjanaphat yeah, that should be the default.

Answer (score -1):

MVC4DP using Universal providers. How about checking configuration or Databases.